# Create new Excel Function (User Defined Function) using C#

Tags: c#, excel, user-defined-functions, excel-dna

I would like to create a new Excel function (user Defined Function), for that i did the same steps as in this link: https://excel-dna.net/

1. I created a class Library Project
2. I installed the package       ExcelDna.Integration
3. I created a method sayHello

But when i try to call my function from a cell in excel (i put =sayHello("World"), the function didn't appear, it seems it's not added to excel functions.
is there some missing steps? how can i make my function appear to be able to use it ?

Comment: seems like a lot of work to do just to add a UDF in excel. Can you not just write it in VBA? or if C# is your preferred language, create a dll and reference it in your excel project

Comment: @Zac While it's faster to make a UDF with VBA, if you want to code in C# or modern VB.NET in Visual Studio, and then use .NET libraries etc., you need a little bit of glue like Excel-DNA to bind the .NET runtime to Excel. Referencing a C# .dll into Excel directly is very restrictive and causes various problems.

Comment: I've never had to use external add-ins so maybe it's my lack of knowledge on the subject. On the back of this, I'll have a look at it and maybe something new for me to learn.. thanks

Answer (score 3):

You should install the package **"ExcelDna.AddIn"** to make the add-in (that will set up the add-in including the important .dna file, and also bring in the **"ExcelDna.Integration"** reference library).

So the steps would be:

- Create a new C# Class Library project (targeting .NET Framework not .NET Standard)
- Install the `ExcelDna.AddIn` package
- Add some code, e.g.

`public static class MyFunctions
    {
        public static string SayHello(string name) { return "Hello " + name; }
    }`

- Press F5 to compile and load the add-in in Excel

(Note that on some Excel installations, the Debug setting for the project get an extra %1 in the executable path - just remove this from the end if you get an error when debugging)

The best support for Excel-DNA is the Google group at https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/exceldna

Comment: Thank u very much, i found this tutorial : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kkihL6vP_tI, it's amazing and everything is ok, it was a simple example to display a message, now i want that my function extract data from database, i created a  method to do this but this time my function doesn't appear,i can't find the problem, my query is ok

Comment: @GtariAbir It might be that your function is not static, or the parameter types are not supported. Write to the Google group if you're still stuck.

Comment: my function is static but it is not public when i define it as public i get this error "Inconsistent accessibility: return type List<AbsProduct> is less accessible than method 'Class1.GetAbsPrice (DateTime)" how can i declare it as public without getting this error please ?

Comment: Oh my class AbsProduct was not declared as public when i defined it as public the problem is solved but when build my solution and try to call my function GetAbsPrice from a cell in excel a window is displayed with this message "Initialization [Error] Method not registered- unsupported signature. abstract or generic:Class1.GetAbsPriceForNav'

Comment: Is it possible to return DataTable to Excel using DNA ? because i change the result type of my function from list to DataTable and i always get the same message "Initialization [Error] Method not registered - unsupported signature, abstract or generic: 'Class1.GetAbsPriceForNav' ", when i change to int or string it works well, does the excel dna support types like list / dataTable or not ? if not how can i change to get many rows from database please ?